# Cut command does not separate by tab in script

Tags: bash, scripting, cut

Note : I don't know how to insert tabulation in my text, I replaced it by [tab]

I have a list file name value separated by a tabulation :

```
host1[tab]ip1
host2[tab]ip2
host3[tab]ip3
host4[tab]ip4
```

Default delimiter of `cut` is [tab], and when I do the following :

```
cut -f1 < file
cut -f2 < file
```

I get my host and my IP as wished. But it does not work in my script

```
while read line
do
  machine=$(echo $line | cut -f1)
  ip=$(echo $line | cut -f2)
  echo "$machine : is my hostname & $ip : is my @IP"
done < file
```

It actually puts the whole line `$line` in the variable.
I also tried this without more success :

```
machine=$(echo $line | cut -d$'\t' -f1)
ip=$(echo $line | cut -d$'\t' -f1)
```

But when I replaced the tabulation by space in the file and modifying my code :

```
machine=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f1)
ip=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f1)
```

It works as expected.

I would like to know why is the first result is different from what expected since it works on the CLI outside of a script.

My Linux version :

```
Linux yolo 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks in advance for reading and helping.

Comment: you are losing the tabs because of the read command

Comment: I did not think about trying the while loop in the CLI and after trying it, the result is the same as the bash script. You are right. I will learn more about the read command. Thank again.

Comment: The solution offered by Marco below is very good though, and you can use echo as well instead of printf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of the `cut` and directly read in the hostname and address in this case:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read -r machine ip
do
  printf '%s : is my hostname & %s : is my @IP\n' "$machine" "$ip"
done < file

exit 0
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I will keep it in mind for this use.

Comment: You can get rid of the `while read` loop and use a tool like awk: `awk '{print $1,": is my  hostname &",$2,": is my @IP"}'`

Comment: @don_crissti Although this question is tagged `bash`, using `awk` is a great solution (avoids the loop and is more efficient) so you should post that as an alternative answer.